# 'already has a default theme' runtime error message

Tags: asp.net, webforms, themes

An ASP.NET webforms app has a theme defined, and a .skin file in Visual Studio.

When I build and run this webapp, I get a run time error:

> GridView already has a default theme defined

I have tried:

- commenting out multiple GridView entries in my theme
- ensuring there's only 1 .skin file in the project

What can I do to solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the project only has 1 .skin file. (in directory)

If you see 2 or more files with the extension **.skin**, then rename extension or delete the ones you don't need.

Hope this helps